# How to use Voximplant text chatting together with React Natiwe?

Tags: react-native, voximplant

Use Voximplant text chatting along with React Native.
Has anyone used it? What ways did you use if there is no plug-in?

Comment: how about 2019? is it working as per needs? I need some help regarding it's implementations, as no any tutorials available on web for same.

Answer (score 0):

Voximplant is used mainly for Voice and Video communications. Text messaging is a pretty new addition and it has not yet landed in the React Native SDK (it will, but in some time).

Comment: how about 2019? is it working as per needs? I need some help regarding it's implementations, as no any tutorials available on web for same.

Comment: It is still not mature enough. Handling notifications is still not perfectly implemented in React Native.